# Batch File to recursively read File Name from directory and input to another command

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have one directory in Windows which has files with certain extensions. I want to read the File Names from the given directory with extension and provide to another command one by one. Below is my scenario :-

```
Directory - D:\Test\
file1.xls.p7
file2.xls.p7
file3.xls.p7
...........
```

I want to read the above file names with extension and provide to below command as :-

```
slift /d file1.xls.p7 /cer <cert_file>
slift /d file2.xls.p7 /cer <cert_file>
slift /d file3.xls.p7 /cer <cert_file>
...........
```

I need to perform the above command recursively for all the files present inside the folder.
The above slift software doesn't support wild card in the command.
I need to perform the same in Batch file. Kindly help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The DIR command is quite flexible, DIR *.p7 >list.txt or something like that will get you your list of files. Then write a FOR loop to read the file one line at a time and call SLIFT inside that loop. The batch file can handle variables just fine, it will substitute the proper text in place of the variable each time the SLIFT command is called. Now somebody is going to come by and lecture you about how we don't write the script for you but we're happy to help with your own script. I would pencil it out for you real quick like, but then I'd get lectured for doing that.

Comment: @Larryc no need to go that cumbersum. `Forfiles` is the choice but `for /f` directly is also possible.

Comment: Yes, agreed, that's yet another way to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forfiles` to do this. It queries all files or by filemask and runs a command for each file it finds.

In your case, the command would be:

```
forfiles /m *.p7 /c "cmd /c slift /d @file /cer file.pfx"
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I was able to perform the task using your command.